# Quarkus build Exception

Tags: quarkus

I have a build exception if I inject this class

```
@Path("/user")
public class CurrentUserResource {

@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;


    @Inject
    UserRepository users;


    @Inject
    PostRepository posts;


    @Inject
    FavoriteRepository favorites;

    @Context
    SecurityContext securityContext;


    @Crypto(Type.BCRYPT)
    @Inject
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @GET
    @Path("/profile")
    public Response user() {
        return users.findByUsername(securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName()).map(p -> ok(p).build())
                .orElse(Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build());

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/favorites")
    public Response favoritedPosts() {
        List<String> slugs = favorites.findByUsername(securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName()).stream()
                .map(f -> f.getPost().getSlug()).collect(toList());
        return ok(slugs).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/posts")
    public Response posts() {
        return ok(posts.findByCreatedBy(securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName())).build();
    }

}
```

And the console log

> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>   io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
>           [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.ciwara.kalanSowApp.security.hashing.PasswordEncoder and qualifiers [@Crypto(value = BCRYPT)]
>           - java member: com.ciwara.kalanSowApp.rest.user.CurrentUserResource#passwordEncoder
>           - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.ciwara.kalanSowApp.rest.user.CurrentUserResource], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.ciwara.kalanSowApp.rest.user.CurrentUserResource]

Comment: What package that contains @Crypto ?

Comment: @Crypto  and CurrentUserResource are in diffents package. There are  no subpackage.